# refer to a row in pivot table python

Tags: python, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in Python now as follows:

```
date    2005-06-30  2005-07-01  2005-07-05  2005-07-06  2005-07-07   
permco                                                               
5         0.006667   -0.006623    0.003333   -0.003322    0.000000   
7         0.012098   -0.008422    0.040548   -0.015534    0.006419   
35       -0.059574   -0.027149    0.000000   -0.037209    0.053140   
36        0.006897    0.027397   -0.080000    0.000000    0.003623   
37       -0.022222    0.020053   -0.019659    0.020053   -0.011796
```

Here, date is the date index and permco is different companies, I have the stock returns in the table.
How can I refer to a row in the table? For example I want to refer to the series:

0.006667   -0.006623    0.003333   -0.003322    0.000000

where permco is 5. However, I tried table.loc[1], table[1], table.loc['permco'=i], etc, nothing works.

Comment: `table.iloc[1]` or `table.loc[5]`?

Comment: Thank you! table.iloc[1] worked

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you can either use :

`df.loc[name_of_index_or_column]`

`df.iloc[number_of_index]`